# Showing large RenderTargetBitmap in the Image element - high memory consumption

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a quite large bitmap (5760x3600px) - a RenderTargetBitmap instance and I need to show it in a window - in a Canvas element. So I used an Image element where I assign the RenderTargetBitmap to the Source property. The bitmap should be shown not stretched. The user can see a middle part of the bitmap in the window and he can drag the image and move the visible part of the image by mouse. The function is OK but the memory consumption is too high.

I know that the bitmap needs cca 160 MB of memory (5760x3600x8) and when I have one RenderTargetBitmap instance only - without showing in the Image element, I really see it takes cca 160 MB of native memory. But when I assign the RenderTargetBitmap to Image.Source, the next 160 MB of RAM is taken. It looks like that the Image element has its own copy of the bitmap.

Is there a way to render the RenderTargetBitmap some way in the canvas without this doubling of memory consumption?

Update:

```cs
RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(5760, 3600, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
myImage.Source = rtb;
```

Comment: Is 160Mb extra memory usage a problem? I would not be surprised if WPF has some extra buffers. 160Mb is not really a lot when most new computers have 16Gb or more, so how much time is it worth to reduce the memory usage?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 160 MB is size of one bitmap. But it is not the only one. I have a memory measuring in the app. It has quite large data saved in lists or dictionaries. After start (without this bitmap not image) it takes cca 490 MB total memory. In this amout, there is 210 MB of native memory, the rest is native memory. When I create a RenderTargetBitmap, the managed memory amount is not significantly changed but native memory usage grows +160 MB. After showing the RenderTargetBitmap in the Image, the total memory consumption is cca 850 MB.

Comment: I use these large bitmaps to create a peace of map. The fastest way to paint polygons and lines is to "paint" them into a WriteableBitmap. But I can't paint strings into WriteableBitmap, so I have a RenderTargetBitmap for rendering of strings. Finally, these two bitmaps are combined into one. First, I placed two Images in the Window. Memory usage were cca 1,2 GB. So I combine the two bitmaps into one DrawingVisual a this one I render into a new RenderTargetBitmap, which is shown in the Image. This takes 850 MB of mem. Without the Image, the usage is 740 MB. Why Image creates a copy of bitmap?

Comment: The Image holds a reference to the source (RenderTargetBitmap), so it can't be garbage collected and has to exist both - rtb and image, each taking 160 MB memory.